# CS50 Filter : Edges my code works fine but can't pass cs50 check

Tags: c, cs50

I'm really stuck here my code works fine but it can not pass CS50 check. I know my code isn't that pretty and has a lot of if conditions and repetition but it works as shown below. I'm new to programming so if anyone has an advice for me I would appreciate it.

[Here is the result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3N7Q.png)

[And here is the results of check50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdKaa.png)

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            temp[h][w] = image[h][w];
            if (h == 0 && w == 0) //check for position 
            {    
                int GxB = (image[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                int GxG = (image[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);
                int GxR = (image[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GyB = (image[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                int GyG = (image[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);
                int GyR = (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                
            else if (h == 0 && w == width - 1) //check for position 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1);
                int GxG = (image[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1);
                int GxR = (image[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1);
                
                int GyB = (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue * 2);
                int GyG = (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen * 2);
                int GyR = (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                
            else if (h == height - 1 && w == 0) //check for position 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 2);
                int GxG = (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 2);
                int GxR = (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1)  + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2);
                
                int GyB = (image[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * -1);
                int GyG = (image[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * -1);
                int GyR = (image[h - 1][w].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * -1);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                
            else if (h == height - 1 && w == width - 1) //check for position 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -2);
                int GxG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -2);
                int GxR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2);
                
                int GyB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue * -2);
                int GyG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen * -2);
                int GyR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtRed * -2);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                
            else if (h == 0) //check for position 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                int GxG = (image[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                int GxR = (image[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GyB = (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                int GyG = (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                int GyR = (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                
            else if (h == height - 1) //check for position 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 2);
                int GxG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 2);
                int GxR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2);
                
                int GyB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * -1);
                int GyG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * -1);
                int GyR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * -1);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                
            else if (w == 0) //check for position 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                int GxG = (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);
                int GxR = (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GyB = (image[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                int GyG = (image[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);
                int GyR = (image[h - 1][w].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                
            else if (w == width - 1) //check for position 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1);
                int GxG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1);
                int GxR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1);
                
                int GyB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue * 2);
                int GyG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen * 2);
                int GyR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
                    
            else 
            {
                int GxB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 2)
                + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                
                int GxG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 2)
                + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);
                
                int GxR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2)
                + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GyB = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * -1)
                + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                
                int GyG = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * -1)
                + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);
                
                int GyR = (image[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[h - 1][w].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * -1)
                + (image[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                
                int GxyB = round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxB*GxB + GyB*GyB));
                int GxyG = round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG*GyG));
                int GxyR = round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) > 255 ? 255 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR)) < 0 ? 0 : round(sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR*GyR));
                
                temp[h][w].rgbtBlue = GxyB;
                temp[h][w].rgbtGreen = GxyG;
                temp[h][w].rgbtRed = GxyR;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            image[h][w] = temp[h][w];
        }
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check50 normally provides more detail for the test results. You can expand the result and see some information about the test data used. Then you can use the same test data and check what your program does.

Comment: TL;DR Reduce the size to 3X3, and add a few printf()s.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments guys I traced the error by using the details in check50 results

Answer (score 0):

I just had a typo where I set all values of Blue Green and Red to the Red value, as soon as I changed every colour to its value my code passed check50.